# Handle DispatcherUnhandledException by not shutdown

Tags: c#, wpf

I know this is a very old issue and saw so many examples here.

My issue caused by Intenet connection. If internet disconnects, the application is shutting down by Dispatch exception.

I do not want to shutdown application on losing internet, rather want to give an alert saying "The internet connection is lost, please connect to the internet" and not shutting down the application. Is there anyway, I can handle this?

Below is my code.

```
 private void UnhandledDispatchException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = e.Exception;
        e.Handled = true;

        this.HandleException("Unhandled Dispatch Exception", ex);
        Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: The odds that you can properly resume running your program when Internet connectivity comes back are pretty low when you do it this way.  You need to try/catch it closer to the code that failed.  Which you need to do it anyway, it will also fall over when the specific server burps for any reason.  Just make sure you can cause this to happen when you need it to happen so you can test your code.  Disabling the network adapter ought to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be triggering the shutdown yourself with `Current.Shutdown()`. Remove that and it should work.

But don't use an unhandled exception event to handle expected errors. Rather, wrap your IO in `try-catch` and handle exceptions near the place they originate from.

Comment: I understand triggering the shutdown myself. But I want to show that error message when it is caused by internet only.

Comment: @Chatra see the 2nd paragraph. Is your question answered?

Comment: Yes, Thank you!